# iPhone Modal View Controller and Device Orientation

Tags: iphone, modalviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation, presentmodalviewcontroller, device-orientation

I'm getting crazy. I have two view controllers (A and B) that supports device orientation.

- In A portrait mode, I modally present B => working well
- In A landscape mode, I modally present B => not working
- When in B, if I change device orientation and dismiss it => not working

By 'not working' I mean the displayed screen is not as expected (graphical objects are not placed where they should be, or do not appear on the screen). I do not know what I should do to prevent that from happening.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

go into interface boulder, in size inspector, set autosizing rules for your views. and dount forget to set them to autoresize.
allso, you can use - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation method to set your views coordinates when device orientation is changed

Comment: Thanks SentineL. But I'm already doing that. If you want, wehn I'm in one of my view controllers, changing device orientation correctly resize and place objects in the view. The issue appears when I move from one view controller to an other (using presentModalViewController and dismissViewController)

Comment: try to call - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation in viewWillAppear

Comment: I tried but still not working. When I dismiss my view controller B. In view controller A is called in order : 
shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationPortrait (which was the device orientation when I present my B view controller). Then viewWillAppear. Inside I added [self shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation]; And so is called shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationLandscape (the device orientation I was when dismissing B view controller). But in fact, the same happened. Hope it is not to confused ^^